# xml format for xmlrpc for metasploit

Tags: xml, xml-rpc, metasploit

I'm trying to have scapy output in form (XML), that I can it to the XMLRPC interface (which is already done) to the metasploit findings db. The problem is not the conversion of information, but I'm struggling finding information about how the xml file has to look like. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no documentation of how the xml has to look like, so that metasploit accepts it.

A small work-around is to take the format of an accepted xml format, like those of nikto, and disguise your information as a nikto scan. Metasploit will then happily accept the information.